# create an array of button that only visible when click the previous button in titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium-alloy

i am still beginner in programming.how to create an add button(that will linked to another UI)once clicked.and then pop up the second add button.After the function is performed by add button,  the first add button changed as item no.1 button that can be edit and remove..
how to solve this problem in titanium.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to place your button within your View element, and then you can use the `$.viewID.hide()` method in your controller and of course you should conditioned it.